# Vuejs transition javascript hook not triggering (nuxtjs)

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, transition

I'm trying to add some animations to my vuejs(v2)+nuxt site using GSAP. To do that I need to trigger some animations on scroll. Vue provides some handy javascript hooks for it but they seem to not be working in my case.

```html
<template>
  <div class="container-xxl">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-12">
        <div class="text-center">
          <transition @before-enter="beforeEnter" @enter="enter" @leave="leave">
            <h1>Test Component</h1>
          </transition>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'TestComponent',
  methods: {
    beforeEnter (el) {
      console.log('before enter')
    },
    enter (el, done) {
      console.log('enter')
    },
    leave (el, done) {
      console.log('leave')
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

When using JavaScript-only transitions, the `done` callbacks are required for the `enter` and `leave` hooks. Otherwise, the hooks will be called synchronously and the transition will finish immediately.